# Android: Android code to convert one audio format to another audio file format

Tags: android

My problem is that i am getting .caf audio file from server in my android device. I want to convert this file in android supported audio formats. Is there any way to do this. Please suggest....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you get to actually convert the files in your android application as the only Java support for CAF was abandoned by Apple over 7 years or so... But if it is a one time, you can try [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to convert your file.